# Convert WORD tables to text (requested member of the collection does not exist.)

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

Perhaps more a WORD issue than VBSCRIPT but my task is simple I just don't know what I'm doing.

The input file is and RTF with 23 tables separated by section breaks.  All content is table except header and footer.  I want to either convert each table to text one by or select all and convert all.  I will ultimately save document as text file.

The following converts one table and then gives collection error.

```
  1  Const RTF="t_14.4.3.1_lbshift.rtf"
  2  Const WDFORMATCODE=2
  3  Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  4  With objWord
  5     .Visible = True
  6     .DisplayAlerts = True
  7     Set objDoc = .Documents.Open(rtf)
  8     t0 = objDoc.Tables.Count
  9        wscript.echo "T0=",t0
 10     for i = 1 to objDoc.Tables.Count
 11        wscript.echo i
 12        .Selection.Tables(i).Select
 13        .Selection.Rows.ConvertToText()
 14        next
 15     End With

T0= 23
1
2

Stderr output:
RTF2PDF.vbs(12, 7) Microsoft Word: The requested member of the collection does not exist.
```

Comment: Maybe the trouble is with `.Selection` in line 12 (and 13?). The `.Selection` looks like its referring to `objWord` but maybe should refer to `objDoc` because `objWord` doesn't have a collection of Table objects. Also, on entering the for-loop nothing is (explicitly) selected, so `.Selection` may be undefined. Then in the for-loop `.Select` looks risky because it will dynamically change the selection. Something like `objDoc.Tables(i).Rows.ConvertToText()` in the for-loop may work.

Comment: When deleting items from collections you should always count down not up. This is because item 2 becomes item 1 when you delete item 1 and consequently the new item 2 is the old item 3 etc.